# Write to javascript console from abstracted class in jupyter notebook

Tags: javascript, python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm working on a project in Jupyter Notebook that uses a custom class that I'm importing into the notebook. Within this class there's a function that I would like to be able to write to the javascript console. It's impractical for this application to just use python's `print()`. Using the `%%javascript` magic won't work because the logging needs to take place within a python function. Is it even possible to write to the javascript console from an imported class? If so, how can I go about it?

Comment: Do you plan to link the ipynb python code with the rendered HTML's source's javascript? I don't think it's possible. If you need to pipe Python and Javascript for the sake of demonstration, you can take a look at [Brython.js](http://brython.info)

Comment: My suspicion was that this wouldn't be possible. It isn't a crucial feature, I just wanted to use the console for some error logging if I could. Thanks!